# Netcat into apache password protected directory

Tags: linux, bash, apache, passwords, netcat

This is a really basic question but I somehow can't figure it out:

I am using netcat to get HTTP response from a website. Example:

```
request="GET / HTTP/1.1"
echo -ne $request | nc 127.0.0.1 80
```

If the website requires authentication I can send a **POST** request and include user/pass in form-data.

But how about apache password protected directories? Let's say this is in my **apache.conf**:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
  ...
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Authentication Required"
  AuthUserFile "/etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd"
  Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

When I visit **127.0.0.1**, I get prompted for user/pass. Browser shows request as "**stalled**". After I provide my credentials, request is finished. If I inspect request headers, I can't find my credentials or any other form data there.

My question is: how are these credentials sent? How can I send them using **netcat** utility?

*p.s.: I am not dead set on using netcat, if there is another command line utility that can achive this in a simple way, that's also great.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are sent in a `Authorization` header, encoded in `base64` (`Wireshark` auto-decodes them for you if you expand the header).

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I see it is in `Authorization` field, but I missed it because of `base64`

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled it, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the username and password easily using `curl`:

```
curl --user name:password localhost
```

You can see how it works by using `-v` to see the headers, for example:

```
curl -sv --user name:password localhost
```

In the header output you will see a line like this:

```
> Authorization: Basic bmFtZTpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CURL insted of netcat